# ToUnicodeEx function fails with any keyboard layout different than mine

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, raw-input, keyboard-layout

I'm using `ToUnicodeEx` function to translate the virtual key code of a pressed key to its unicode character,

This is the function definition:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi)>
Friend Shared Function ToUnicodeEx(
                       ByVal wVirtKey As UInteger,
                       ByVal wScanCode As UInteger,
                       ByVal lpKeyState As Byte(),
                       <Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>
                       ByVal pwszBuff As StringBuilder,
                       ByVal cchBuff As Integer,
                       ByVal wFlags As UInteger,
                       ByVal dwhkl As IntPtr
) As Integer
End Function
```

The function works perfect for my culture **es-ES** with my keyboard layout **3082**, however, if instead specifying **3082** I try the code below specifying a **1033** keyboard layout to simulate a key pres for **en-US** culture, or whatever any other keyboard layout different than **3082**, then `ToUnicodeEx` function will fail and returns 0, where a return value of 0 means this:

> The specified virtual key has no translation for the current state of
>   the keyboard.  Nothing was written to the buffer specified by
>   pwszBuff.

```
Dim buf As New StringBuilder(256)
Dim keyboardState As Byte() = New Byte(255) {}

If shift Then
    keyboardState(CInt(Keys.ShiftKey)) = &HFF
End If

If altGr Then
    keyboardState(CInt(Keys.ControlKey)) = &HFF
    keyboardState(CInt(Keys.Menu)) = &HFF
End If

InputDevice.NativeMethods.ToUnicodeEx(CUInt(Keys.A), 0UI, keyboardState,  buf,  256,  0UI, 
                                      New IntPtr(1033))
```

What I'm doing wrong?, How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimenting, reasearching, and with some fails, I found in the .Net framework class library the best and easier solution that does not involves P/Invoking.

Just knowing a culturename, like **en-US** or **es-ES** with the `Systwm.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage` class we can retrieve the handle of the layout (the HKL)

```
InputLanguage.FromCulture(New CultureInfo("en-US")).Handle
```

Then, that value can be set for the `dwHKL` parameter of the `ToUnicodeEx` function, and it works perfect!.

Comment: What is your intent?  Do you want to find how this key event **would behave on somebody else’s computer**?!  Since the returned keyboard may have nothing to do with the currently selected keyboard…  (At least when you have many keyboards associated to a language.) — I discussed the “correct” way in another comment.

Comment: (I put “correct” in quotes since using `ToUnicode{Ex}()` without knowing what you do may be dangerous.  In most cases, one wants to use the non-destructive mode — which may be tricky.)

Comment: Thanks for comment. The intention was to develop a universal, reusable, and educative keyboard logger. Having a class with name "KeyboardMonitor", that exposes an event: "KeyPressed As EventHandler(Of KeyPressedEventArgs)" which relies on a function with signature: "GetCharsFromKeys(key As Keys, shift As Boolean, altGr As Boolean) As String" - that it should translate (with the help to function 'ToUnicodeEx') the current pressed key to a string (a single character, or composed characters). This code is missing some other referenced classes but you get the idea: https://pastebin.com/ASUYSBsh

Comment: Do not see how this may work.  The effect of the pressed key depends not only on the pressed-state of `Shift` and `AltGr`, but also on the pressed-state of **any other** key — not even mentioning the toggle-state of `CapsLock` and `NumLock`. 
 To add insult to injury, there is also `Alt-NumPad` input — which also depends on the history and the state of the registry. 
 One should also be able to keep in mind the dead-key state (reporting of which is plagued by bugs in `ToUnicode`.  (I wrote a “universal handler of keyboard” which — in particular — does the logging as you wished to do.)  Etc.

Comment: For this handler, I identified 15 different scenarios of user doing input/keyboard␣control␣of␣application.  (As of today, only 13 are implemented.)

Comment: For input of “non-base” characters, many keyboard layouts (including default Microsoft layouts for certain localities) either do not use `AltGr` at all, — or use it very sparingly  E.g., my layouts **do** use `AltGr`, but in fact currently they use 6 **different** modifiers (and I plan to use 3 more to add more orthogonality/support␣of␣deficient␣hardware).

Comment: @Ilya Zakharevich That source-code was written more than nine years ago, while I was learning many new things, and learning .NET in general (less than two years programming in VB.NET). That logger it was never completed as I would like (abandoned). It just worked fine, or seemed to work fine, under my environment, using a Spanish of Spain ("es-ES") keyboard layout. Still many things that I ignore in order to accomplish the objectives. Thanks for your help and suggestions!. I could find the universal handler somewhere, or it is a private code?.

Comment: I would like to see a source-code of a professional / specialized programmer with good understanding about keyboard and keys, like you seem, in order to learn from you, and to try improve my own source-code taking inspiration, and implementing similar logic to do things in the (same) right way. In any case, thank you again!.

Comment: Right now this “handler” is still very buggy/fragile to be inspirational to others.  And even when/if the defects are sorted out, one should remember that its purpose is “to work around quirks/bugs in what Microsoft designed and made”.  Such workarounds are destined to be — at best — collections of hacks; hardly something to inspire… (Although I would very much like to inspire people to **think of user-input** as of something *which may be done* in an [almost] bullet-proof ways.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply pass a number (`IntPtr`) as the last parameter... As written in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646322.aspx)

> dwhkl [in, optional]
>   Type: HKL
>   The input locale identifier used to translate the specified code. This parameter can be any input locale identifier **previously returned by the LoadKeyboardLayout function.**

You must load the layout with `LoadKeyboardLayout` first.

Comment: But that function changes the keyboard layout in the entire O.S!. Additional info is required, what I would like to do is use a different keyboard layout without affecting the Os behavior. thanks anyways!.

Comment: I changed accidentally the keyboard layout with `LoadKeyboardLayout` then I will ask first this time. The documentation of the first parameter of  `ActivateKeyboardLayout` says: `The input locale identifier must have been loaded by a previous call to the LoadKeyboardLayout function`, its saying that I should use the other function that I will avoid because it changes the layout on the OS. then what I should do?.

Comment: Call [`GetKeyboardLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout) instead.

Comment: Also, I do not think this is documented, but one can use `0` to mean “the current layout”.  Or just use `ToUnicode` instead!